# Linux expect not returning control to bash script after using interact

Tags: linux, automation, tcl, expect

My goal is to automate the following

- From a master shell script, log in to a remote SSH session (passwordless key is already steup)
- I then need root access, so I am using expect to log me in, i.e. **send "su", expect "Password:", send ""** which works.
- Then I want to release control from expect back to the bash script that called the expect script and run various SSH commands logged in as root.

Is this possible or do I have to do everything via expect?

Comment: What's not working? Show some evidence that we can see. It's usually helpful to run expect with debugging enabled so you can see what's going on (`expect -d script.exp`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that the various layers of communication have to remain in place; there's more going on than you're aware of.

Your model is this:

```
+------+   expect   +-----+   su   +----------------+
| bash | ---------> | ssh | -----> | remote-context | 
+------+            +-----+        +----------------+
```

But what's actually going on is this:

```
+----------------+   +----------------------+   +----------------------------+
| local terminal |   |        expect        |   |       remote terminal      |
|                |   | +------------------+ |   | +------------------------+ |
|    +------+    |   | | virtual terminal | |   | |          bash          | |
|    | bash | -----> | |                  | |   | | +--------------------+ | |
|    +------+    |   | |     +-----+      | |   | | |         su         | | |
|                |   | |     | ssh | ---------> | | | +----------------+ | | |
+----------------+   | |     +-----+      | |   | | | | remote context | | | |
                     | +------------------+ |   | | | +----------------+ | | |
                     +----------------------+   | | +--------------------+ | |
                                                | +------------------------+ |
                                                +----------------------------+
```

Or something like that (I've omitted most of the bits to do with the network, for example). There's a *lot* of layering going on, most of which you're unaware of. But because `ssh` is running inside `expect` (in order to take advantage of the automation capabilities) it means that `ssh` is running in a local virtual terminal controlled by `expect`; `bash` can't take control directly, and `expect` can't cut itself out of the loop (since `bash` doesn't know how to be the master side of a virtual terminal; `expect` and `sshd` *do* know that).

Instead, you need to either write the remainder of your code inside expect directly, or provide the code that is to be run as an argument (in some sense; perhaps pulled from a file?) that it can pass on via `send`.

Expect gets arguments from the `argv` variable, can use `gets stdin` to read a line of text from its caller, and `open`/`read`/`close` to pull in the contents of a file.

---

Are you aware of `sudo` as an alternative to `su`? That can be configured to allow fully password-free operation for a particular requesting user. That can be useful to allow operation of the system without exposing too large a security hole. You should also consider switching to a form of `ssh` that works better for automation, such as:

```
spawn ssh $remotehost sudo /usr/local/bin/DoTheWonderfulThing
```

This sort of thing, once it works, has fewer pieces that can go wrong in unexpected ways…

Comment: Thanks that's a great summary of the issue I am facing. Will give some of those suggestions a go!